# How Can I Prevent SSRS query of XML data from Always Returning an Empty Row?

Tags: xml, datasource, ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a dataset from an XML file in SSRS 2008. Below is a simple piece of XML that shows my problem:

```
<Company>
</Company>
```

When using the following as the Query it returns a single row with empty fields for the ID and the Name.

```
Company{}/People{ID(String), Name(String)}
```

As you can see there is no `<People>` element present in the XML and therefore I was expecting it to return an empty dataset (i.e. one with no rows).

Does anyone know of a way to return an empty dataset in these circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer - but a workaround:

I ended up hiding the spurious row using a visibility expression like:

```
<Hidden>Len(Fields!ID.Value) > 0 AND Len(Fields!Name.Value) > 0</Hidden>
```