# SSRS returns a DataSet with One Row when XPATH doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server-2008, xpath, reporting-services

SSRS 2008 R2

This is essentially a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646588/how-can-i-prevent-ssrs-query-of-xml-data-from-always-returning-an-empty-row).

...but the solution posted there doesn't work for me.

It is important to note that if there is data at all, then everything works fine for me.

Why is it that SSRS will return a DataSet with one row if you query with an XPATH that doesn't resolve in the XML document?

For example, if I have a DataSet called "Address":

```
<Country>
</Country>
```

Any my XPATH is:

```
Country/City{Street}
```

(For example)

I get a DataSet back with one row and every field in that row seems to be an error - in that any operation I perform on it fails.  So I can't even put a hidden filter on it because my hide expression fails to execute and the row is shown - totally blank.

If the City element is there then it is fine.

In testing if I try to create a TextBox and do ANY operations on fields in that one row, they all fail and the entire TextBox just doesn't show up even if there are string literals in it.

For example, if I put a TextBox with the expression:

```
="Rows: " & CountRows("Address")
```

I get the result:

```
1
```

But if I change that same text box (in a table cell) to:

```
="Rows: " & CountRows("Address") & " Hide:" & IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Street.Value), "yes", "no")
```

The text box just doesn't show up at all, but the table row still gets drawn and is blank.

I've encountered this in many placed and have always managed to hack it out at the source XML, but in this case that isn't possible.

What is going on with that one row in the DataSet?

Comment: ...learned that at least you can use IsMissing to determine if something is completely absent, but you'd have to do this for every element in the dataset.  Would still love to know what the content of that one row where nothing exists is!

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to your XPath query to filter out the empty elements.

Something like:

```
Country/City{Street}[string-length(Street) &gt; 0]
```

or maybe?

```
Country/City[string-length(Street) &gt; 0]{Street}
```

(my XPath is a little rusty...]

Comment: Thanks for the tip - issue is my example is very simple and in reality this will lead to some extremely complex XPath queries (I'm looking at just shy of 100 elements and any one of them may legally be empty).

I'm actually very interested in learning what SSRS is doing here.  What does that one row in the DataSet represent?  It is a row that, from what I can tell, you cannot interact with in anyway - so what is its purpose?  Maybe it contains error information and there is a reserved field available to retrieve the error from?  (Just a theory, but at least that would kind of make sense.)